# Login script creation in RAZOR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, razor

i have a basic razor project where i am trying to create a login page.

i have a problem with storing the current user information. In this class i have this code:

```
public User currentUser { get; set; }
    public void OnPostLogin()
    {
           //lists in database for every user with the input "UserNameLogin" username
        foreach(DataRow dr in db.ParametryUzivatele(UserNameLogin).Rows)
        {
            if(PasswordLogin == dr[2].ToString())
            {
                 //the inside of an if statement is gonna be replaced with BCrypt verification
                 //if password matches, it saves all the info from the database about the user in to the currentUser object.
                    currentUser = new(dr[0].ToString(), dr[1].ToString(), dr[2].ToString(), dr[3].ToString(), dr[4].ToString(), dr[5].ToString());  
            }
        }
        
    }
```

the current user is stored as an object of type User (model class).
Right now it is stored in the back of the LoginPage, but after leaving the page, the object gets a new instance, and loses the values.
Where and how should i save the code?

Comment: Have you tried to save the value of `currentUser` into session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, If you want to store the current user information across multiple pages, You can use [Session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to achieve it.

Create an extension method on session in a static class：

```
public static class TestSession
    {
        //set session
        public static void SetObjectsession(this ISession session, string key, object value)
        {
            session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
        }

        //get session
        public static T GetObjectsession<T>(this ISession session, string key)
        {
            var value = session.GetString(key);
            return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
        }
    }
```

In `OnPostLogin()` method

```
currentUser = new(dr[0].ToString(), dr[1].ToString(), dr[2].ToString(), dr[3].ToString(), dr[4].ToString(), dr[5].ToString());
HttpContext.Session.SetObjectsession("currentuser", currentUser );
```

In other pages use:

```
var result = HttpContext.Session.GetObjectsession<User>("currentuser");
```

to get the value of currentUser.

====================Update=================

I put the `SetObjectsession` method into my `privacy.cshtml.cs`, When I first access `Index.cshtml`, `HttpContext.Session.GetObjectsession<User>("currentuser")` will be null. After i access privacy and access `Index.cshtml` again, It will have value.

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
    var reuslt = HttpContext.Session.GetObjectsession<User>("currentuser");
}

@if (reuslt != null)
{
    <h1>@reuslt.UserName</h1>
}
else
{
    <h1>current user is null</h1>
}
```

**Gif Demo**

[image]

Comment: That sounds like the solution to me!
I am testing it but the "JsonConvert.DeserializeObject....." doesnt exist, does it need a nuget package?

Comment: @Drapys
Yes, you need to use `Newtonsoft.Json` package

Comment: @Drapys, Have your issue been solved now?

Comment: Working on it right now, i am having troubles with the get, as the page opens for the first time, the currentuser variable is null, so it probably has an exception and the page doesnt show.
But when i put the iif(HttpContext.Session.GetObjectsession<User>("currentuser") is null)
It still goes to else
dont know what could the variable has inside so i can make the if statement right?

Comment: Do you mean when you don't set any session, So you can only get null from `GetObjectsession`, Then the page will show exception? What kind of exception? Could you explain more details about it?

Comment: when i put this line of code "var currentuser = HttpContext.Session.GetObjectsession<User>("currentuser");" inside the Index.cshtml page, the page doesnt load at all, and i think its because the GetObjectSession is empty before the user logs in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253492/discussion-between-xinran-shen-and-drapys).